# OLAP connection manager not working with dynamic values from SSIS config file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2017, ssis-2017

Could anyone provide suggestion to fix on the below issue in  my SSIS package.
I have a SSIS package designed to process SSAS cube on automated basis.first step involved is dimension processing and second is processing cube.

1. SSIS package works fine and process cube in DEV environment
2. Now generated XMLA script  from development cube and created cube
   structure in Testing environment
3. Ran SSIS package again with test environment config to process
   cube in testing environment
4. Cube process fails and observed that OLAP connection manager is
   not picking values from SSIS package config file. Runs only with
   design time value irrespective of the environment deployed

please confirm is this issue with OLAP connection manager or expected behavior.

Is there any fix available to make it work

Note: using SQL server 2017 version

Many thanks

karthi

Comment: Hi @Karthi, inspect for warning messages, looks like the configuration has failed to apply

Comment: Hi Arthur, There is no warning messages generated. In the same config file one oledb  and OLAP connection manager are there. Oledb connection manager works fine based on config file but OLAP connection manager create the issue

Comment: please share how you made the configuration